# Erro write failed: No space left on device

Tags: php

Ao reinstalar o servidor Apache e PHP na minha máquina estou recebendo este erro:

> Warning: Unknown(): write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0

E se tento executar algum script com sessão, além deste erro, recebo o seguinte erro:

> Warning: Unknown(): Failed to write session data (files). 
>   Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: qual distro e qual comando vc está usando para instalar?

Comment: @AdirKuhn http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Antes de dar um voto negativo entenda o modelo da comunidade, leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer e http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange e se tiver algum outro motivo pro downvote justifique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este problema costuma ocorrer por motivos como:

- O diretório configurado (no caso `/tmp`) não tem permissão para escrita.
- O diretório não permite acesso do usuário atual (o servidor pode ter acesso do usuário principal, mas o diretório só tem acesso por *root*).
- Pode ser um diretório que não existe.

O diretório `/tmp` é apenas um exemplo, veja outra situação do problema:

> Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/opt/lampp/tmp/session) in Unknown on line 0

Neste caso foi instalado o servidor *lampp* em uma máquina like-unix e é provável que a pasta `/opt/lampp/tmp/session` não seja acessível (por um dos motivos já descritos).

No caso do problema é provável que também retorne este erro:

> Warning: Unknown(): Failed to write session data (files).

### Possíveis soluções:

1. Se o diretório não existir devemos editar o arquivo *php.ini* e configurar para um diretório válido:
   Procure no arquivo *php.ini* está linha e altere-a:

   ```
   session.save_path = /home/user/tmp;
   ```

   Se for um servidor/maquina Windows seria algo como:

   ```
   session.save_path = c:/wamp/tmp;
   ```
2. Se você estiver tiver feito a modificação *php.ini* e mesmo assim o problema ocorre, pode ser que você esteja em um "servidor virtual", portanto alteração tem que ser no tal servidor.
3. Se tiver certeza que não é um servidor virtual ou que alterou o arquivo certo, então é por que você necessita reiniciar o servidor (não precisa reiniciar a máquina inteira):

   Se for Apache, no terminal use o comando:

   `apache2 restart` ou com `SU` use `sudo apache2 restart`
4. Se tiver reiniciado (mesmo que a máquina), o problema pode ser nas permissões da pasta.
   Para alterar as permissões, use o seguinte comando:

   `chmod 1777 /tmp`

> **Nota:** Em sistemas like-unix não é necessário permitir o acesso da pasta que ficará a sessão para todos usuário (usuário do sistema operacional), somente o usuário que o *serviço* está rodando.

Outra solução é configurar usando (no caso do problema ser com `session_start`) o `session_save_path`:

```
session_save_path('/home/user/tmp');
```

Agora se por algum motivo você estiver usando um serviço de hospedagem e você não tiver acesso ao *php.ini* e o `session_save_path` estiver desabilitado só existe uma solução, procurar o suporte técnico da empresa que está lhe prestando o serviço, através de *ticket*, *telefone* ou *email* (em alguns casos chat).