# Erro de Sessão - Permission denied - sites em portas diferentes

Tags: php, session

Olá, boa tarde. 
Estou a algum tempo tentando resolver este problema:
Tenho um site que roda na porta padrão e um sistema administrativo que roda na porta 8080. (ex: https://www.dominio.com.br e http://www.dominio.com.br:8080/adm )

Quando no mesmo browser, faço login no site da porta :8080 e em seguida no site da porta padrão, ele faz o processo normalmente, acaba com a sessão gerada pela porta :8080 e gera uma nova. Já quando tento o processo inverso, logar pela porta padrão e depois no :8080, obtenho o seguinte erro:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]:
>   open(C:\xx\xx\sess_malaee35psko2uv3rsjhmfd0e3, O_RDWR) failed:
>   Permission denied (13) in
>   C:\xx\xx\login.php on line 2

Em ambos os sistemas, o usuário web é utilizado, em um eu consigo acessar a sessão e no outro não.
Procurei bastante nos foruns e não achei nada referente sobre a questão das portas e o erro de permissão. Mudei a permissão do diretório de sessões para 777 e não tive mais o erro, porém, como o acesso vem do mesmo lugar, para o mesmo lugar, gostaria de saber o motivo disso, de um lado conseguir apagar e do outro não.

Desde já, grato pela atenção.

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente esta usando [iis](/questions/tagged/iis) ou *php-built in server*, provavelmente a maneira que configurou o PHP a sessão deve estar tentando gravar em `c:\windows\temp` mas o IIS não esta rodando com privilégios de administrador, para resolver basta apontar uma pasta **"não publica"** para salvar a sessão, pode configurar isto no php.ini como expliquei em [*Erro write failed: No space left on device*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51161/3635)

Troque no php.ini para algo como (a pasta `outra-pasta/pastadetemporarios` deve existir):

```
session.save_path = c:/outra-pasta/pastadetemporarios
```

Ou pode ajustar no começo do seu script php:

```
<?php
session_save_path('c:/outra-pasta/pastadetemporarios');
```

> A pasta deve estar em usuário que o IIS esta usando (se estiver usando IIS) ou então deve estar em uma pasta o qual o usuário principal o qual iniciou o servidor

Comment: Sim Guilherme, iis XI. Então, a configuração do PHP é a mesma para ambas as portas e o diretório é PHP/sessions para ambas também.
Consigo gerar e manipular sessão em ambas as portas, porém, quando tento modificar a sessão gerada na porta padrão, acessando pela porta :8080 não consigo (inverso eu consigo). O acesso é feito pelo mesmo usuário de internet.

Comment: @DiegoAndrade sim, porque deve estar usando talvez um proxy-inverso ou 2 servidores na mesma máquina, no entanto estão em usuário diferentes (usuário do windows), um deles deve iniciar em root e outro não.

Comment: Hm, entendi! Vou verificar sobre o proxy  e retorno aqui. Possivelmente este é o problema... Sobre o servidor, ele roda no mesmo. Só o direcionamento da porta que é feito em diretórios diferentes.  Muito obrigado Guilherme.

Comment: @DiegoAndrade por nada, qualquer novidade só me avisar ;)