# SESSION PHP LOGIN

Tags: php, session, login

Estou tendo problemas ao criar uma session no php. É como se ela simplesmente "não criasse", quando vou validar se ela existe com isset é como se ela não existisse.

Não sei em que estou errando, aqui vai o código de validação:

```
<?php

include_once("conexao.php");

$usuario_adm = $_POST['usuario_adm'];
$senha_adm = $_POST['senha_adm'];

$sql = "select  * from adm where usuario='$usuario_adm' and senha='$senha_adm'";
$res = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
$linhas = mysqli_num_rows($res);

if ($linhas == ''){
    header("Location: soldaforte.php");
}

else {

    while ($dados=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['adm_usu'] = $dados['nome_usu'];
        header("Location: empresa.php");
    }
}

mysqli_close($conexao);


?>
```

```php
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['adm_usu'])){
    header("Location: soldaforte.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Se a resposta mostrando a correção no `while` não funcionar, vale apena você verificar se o `session.save_path` do seu PHP *(normalmente no linux em `/var/lib/php/sessions`)* esta com as permissões corretas, e se as sessions estão sendo criadas nesse diretorio.

Comment: Anna, o que garante que o código está executando como você acha que está? Se a sua consulta não possuir registros, o valor de `$linhas` será 0; você compara com uma *string* vazia (o que é bem esquisito) e o resultado da comparação seria `true`, redirecionando o usuário para `soldaforte.php`. Se acontecer o que você diz que está acontecendo, o usuário também será redirecionado para `soldaforte.php` quando a sessão não existir. Como sabe qual das duas situações está ocorrendo?

Comment: Quando você diz registros, está se referindo ao banco? Sorry, sou iniciante no PHP :p

Comment: @AnnaGabriela Sim, se o registro com o usuário e senha informados não for encontrado, `$linhas` será 0.

Comment: Meus registros no banco estão ok, acabei de conferir :)

Comment: cara anna, troque `if ($linhas == ''){` por `if ($linhas == 0){`, porque `mysqli_num_rows` sempre retorna numeros, nunca retornará uma string vazia como respondi em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/391326/3635 se ainda algo falhar é porque pode ter mais problemas, então leia o resto da resposta.

Comment: Fiz isso amigo, não deu certo :/

Answer (score 2):

Creio que o erro é isto:

```
if ($linhas == ''){
```

Troque por:

```
if ($linhas == 0){
```

Porque `mysqli_num_rows` retorna sempre `int` e não string vazia, no caso quando não tem resultados retornará zero (`0`)

---

Agora se a falha continuar **faça um teste simples**, troque TODOS `session_start()` por `session_start() or die('A sessão não pode ser iniciada');`, assim:

```
<?php

include_once("conexao.php") or die('A sessão não pode ser iniciada');

$usuario_adm = $_POST['usuario_adm'];
$senha_adm = $_POST['senha_adm'];

$sql = "select  * from adm where usuario='$usuario_adm' and senha='$senha_adm'";
$res = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
$linhas = mysqli_num_rows($res);

if ($linhas == ''){
    header("Location: soldaforte.php");
}

else {

    while ($dados=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['adm_usu'] = $dados['nome_usu'];
        header("Location: empresa.php");
    }
}

mysqli_close($conexao);

?>
```

O outro arquivo

```
<?php

session_start() or die('A sessão não pode ser iniciada');

if (!isset($_SESSION['adm_usu'])){
    header("Location: soldaforte.php");
}
?>
```

Digo isto, porque é provável que tenha algum espaço em "branco acima" até mesmo invisível no editor de textos/script, se aparecer a mensagem:

> A sessão não pode ser iniciada

É que de fato a sessão não inicio e provavelmente os erros estão desligados no seu servidor, podendo ser o level do `error_reporting` ou o `display_errors` estar em Off

Neste caso se você estiver em `localhost` ligue todos erros no seu `php.ini`, se sabe como editar, procure essa linha (isto é para definir o level de captura de erros para o log):

```
error_reporting=
```

Mude o valor dela para

```
error_reporting=E_ALL
```

E então procure a linha `display_errors=`, troque o valor para:

```
display_errors=On
```

> **Recomendo que leia** [Por que usar error_reporting com display_errors e display_startup_errors?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106562/3635) para entender sobre cada flag e configuração de log do PHP

Reiniciei o seu servidor local, seja apache, seja nginx, seja o que for, é preciso reinicia-lo completamente, se não conseguir simplesmente faça o logoff do teu usuário e logue novamente e então inicie o teu servidor.

Então após isso teste os scripts, é provavel que o session_start() vá emitir um *warning* assim:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at

Então realmente é um erro de espaçamento, você pode ter salvo os scripts como **UTF-8 com B.O.M**, para resolver leia isto:

- [Erro - "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4251/3635) (a resposta mais votada é excelente, leia com calma que nunca mais irá passar por este problema, entender as tecnologias é mais importante que pegar soluções prontas :) )

**Agora atenção**, se o erro for este:

> Warning: Unknown: open(..., O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0

Então o problema é muito mais grave, a pasta que ficam os arquivos de sessão é inacessível ao PHP (ou usuário do Apache/Ngnix etc), então isto pode ajudar:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206614/3635

Mas é uma solução alternativa, apesar de aonde salvar essas sessões é escolha de quem configura o servidor, desde que não salve em locais publicos, como `./www` ou `./public_html`

Outro erro semelhante, que ocorreu comigo inclusive em hospedagens "profissionais" foi este:

> Warning: Unknown(): write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0

- O diretório configurado (no caso /tmp) não tem permissão para escrita.
- O diretório não permite acesso do usuário atual (o servidor pode ter acesso do usuário - principal, mas o diretório só tem acesso por root).
- Pode ser um diretório que não existe.

Basicamente a mesma solução: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51161/3635

Comment: Cara, obrigada por tentar me ajudar. Porém, ainda não é isso. Troquei o $linhas == " " por $linhas == 0 e coloquei o or die em todos os session_start(), mas minha sessão está inciando normalmente. Parece que apenas quando coloco o isset dá um bug :/

Comment: @AnnaGabriela bug não é, com toda certeza. No segundo arquivo, que valida, remova temporariamente a linha `header("Location: soldaforte.php");` e faça assim: `<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['adm_usu'])){
    var_dump($_SESSION);
}
?>`, tenta logar e depois verifica se o var_dump retornou algo.